# .htaccess; how to get subfolder but don't show in URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's say I call `www.expamle.com` in browser. That'll get the data from `/` on my server.

But how can I get the data from `/folder/` on my server but still able to call from `www.expamle.com` and also remain `www.expamle.com` as browser address?

Additionally e.g. `www.expamle.com/my_file.php` should be called from `/folder/my_file.php` on my server.

How can I do that with `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule !^folder /folder%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This will rewrite all requests including existing files and subfolders from your root to the /folder . If you dont want to rewrite your existing root files and folders, you can use this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /folder%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below rule too,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [QSA,L]
```